# How to achieve URL patterns in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a web portal. I need to achieve below mentioned URL structure in codeigniter.

> xyz.com/car-dealers/state1/
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/brand1/
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/brand1/location1
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/used-cars/
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/new-cars/
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/vineet-motors/
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/authorized/new-cars/brand1/location1
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/authorized/brand1
>
> xyz.com/car-dealers/authorized/brand1/location1

How i can achieve this?  Client is a Digital Marketing Guru and  he is demanding the same URL pattern.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You can customize your URL in `config/routes.php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the below to make it better.

1. Base URL (in your case xyz.com)
2. Controller (in your case lets consider the controller name `cars`)
3. A method in the controller (you can have default `index` too)
4. Parameters for the controller method (`$param1, $param2, $param3` etc.,)

You can then configure `routes.php` or `.htaccess` file to navigate `xyz.com/car-dealers/brand1` to load the controller with parameters `xyz.com/cars/brand1`

You have to plan the pattern (parameters) accordingly and then you can easily do it. This leaves you to explore it on your own further. Try it out.